# How do I connect a search Textfield with a combobox in order to filter the results on the jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to filter the search textfield connected on my jtable using my combobox. My combobox has 4 Items; the same as the columns I have on my jTable, named "Employee Number", "First Name", "Middle Name" and "Last Name".

This is for java with no database, so it should not be that complicated. But sadly, I can't do it. I coded this on my search textfield keytyped and I the people with the given employee number or name that were typed are now popping out. But I can't filter it using my combobox, still.

```
 DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
 String search = searchbar.getText();
 TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(dtm);
 jTable1.setRowSorter(tr);
 tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search));
```

If I choose "Employee Number" on my combobox and i enter the last name of an employee on my search bar, the result MUST NOT come out. But if I choose "Last Name" on my combobox, then only it will come out. Same goes for the other 3 parts of the combobox. I hope someone wouldbe able to help me do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would be nice if you can share your project with us :)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table.